# Saved webpage javascript don't work locally?

Tags: javascript

I found a site for testing your knowledge on html elements with a timed test( http://thehtml5quiz.com/ ). I want to save the page and it work locally, so that I can alter the test to suit my studying needs.

When I save the page, and open it in the browser, it goes directly to the test being finished and you never get a chance to take the test.

Im still studying css and haven't made it to javascript yet.

I would really appreciate any help on getting this going, as it would help me learn much faster if I could create my own memorization tests.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you use the built-in "Save As..." functionality?

Comment: check the console and network tab in dev tools. chances are the site was built in a way that depends on other site based resources and wouldn't just work if saved like this. Sometimes you can fake it a little by saving each dependent file, so long as the questions aren't fetched on the fly via an ajax call. Just saying, most sites these days are more complex than a simple save utility can handle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the page as 'Webpage, Complete'. This should give you all the supporting files in a sub directory

Comment: using chrome, right click -> save as -> webpage, Complete. All files are downloaded. Doesn't work.